# When starting app.js, gives me "cannot read property of undefined" error in index.js

Tags: javascript, express, middleware

When I try to node app.js on my domain it gives me a "TypeError: Cannot read property 'slice' of undefined" and mentions index.js However I ran this in my local webhost in my computer and it worked just fine... what is blocking this? My domain is run on ubuntu with all modules required in the script file already installed. I checked the source code in the url of the request and it is not undefined... that is weird.

Here is the code from index.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const request = require('request');
const cheerio = require('cheerio');
const fs = require('fs');
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const ep = new AWS.Endpoint('*censored*.amazonaws.com');
const db = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({      // Dynamo database constructor
    "apiVersion": '2012-08-10',
    "region": 'us-west-1',
    "endpoint": ep,
    "accessKeyId": '*censored*CA',
    "secretAccessKey": '+*censored*o6n'
});


var url = "https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&gl=us&tbm=nws&authuser=0&q=u.s.&oq=u.s.&num=100&start=0";

//------  START MIDDLE WARE STUFF --------------  ---------------------------------------------------------------
router.use(function timeLog (req, res, next) {
  next();
});
/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index');
});
module.exports = router; /*function(req,res,next) {
    res.render('index');
};*/
//------  END MIDDLE WARE STUFF --------------  ----------------------------------------------------------------- 





/* ------------------------------------------ ARTICLES -------------------------------------------------------- */
    // this will be called after we collect our "subject" article"
var checkArticle = function (title, date, source, url, description) {

    this.title = title;
    this.date = date;
    this.url = url;
    this.source = source;
    this.description = description;
    // set it to date inserted to database
    date = new Date().toLocaleString();

    //invoke a seperate function now! make two things process at once. 
    //goes inside the subject article and grabs the image/description
    let params = {
        TableName: "Articles"
    };

    db.scan(params, function(err,scannedData) {
        if (err) throw err;
            // scanData = target check
            // title + date + url + author = our subject article to check
            //asynchronously invoke a seperate function to display the current news right away, so there is no wait time

        console.log(`\n\n-------------------------------Subject Article:------------------------------- \n`);
        console.log("Title: " + title);
        console.log("Date: " + date);
        console.log("Source: " + source)
        console.log("description: " + description + '\n');
        console.log("URL: " + url);
            // pass this step to next function
        return Result(title, date, source, url, description, scannedData);
    });

    function Result(title, date, source, url, description,scannedData) {
        console.log("Peforming check...")
        let counter = 0;
            // peform check on all items. using 'counter' as the logic variable
        for (var i = 0; i < scannedData.Items.length; i++) {
            if (title === scannedData.Items[i].title) {
                counter++;
                console.log("We found a match. We are not performing anymore operations. \n -----------------------------------------------------------------------------");
                return console.log("Stopped from inserting article to database.");
            }
        }
            // if a  match was found, it will execute this. Adds item to database
        if (counter === 0) {
            let params = {
                TableName: "Articles",
                Item: {
                    title: title,
                    date: date,
                    url: url,
                    source: source,
                    description: description
                }
            }
            db.put(params, function(err) {
                if (err) throw err;
                else { return; }
            });
            console.log("No matches found. Inserted article to 'Articles' database");
        }
    }
}



    // This is for Front Page, news portion initiation
    request(url, 'w+', function(err,data,body) {
        if (err) throw err;
        var $ = cheerio.load(body);
        //console.log($(".slp").prev().eq(2).text());   // title
        //console.log($(".slp").prev().children().eq(0).attr('href')); // url
        //console.log($(".slp").children().html());   // New York Times - 3 hours ago      //source - date
        //console.log($("div.st").eq(0).text());    // description
        let regExp = / - /;
        console.log($(".slp").prev().children().eq(0).attr('href'));
        let urlSlice1 = $(".slp").prev().children().eq(0).attr('href').slice(7,Infinity);
        let urlSlice2 = urlSlice1.search(/&/);
        let urlSliced = urlSlice1.slice(0, urlSlice2);
        let hyphenBreakerForSource = $(".slp").children().html().search(regExp, "");        // gives the index # of found regExp
        //    got our meat of the burger.   //  /   /   //  //
        let source = $(".slp").children().html().slice(0,hyphenBreakerForSource);   //source 
        let date = $(".slp").children().html().slice(hyphenBreakerForSource + 3);       //date
        let url = urlSliced;
        let description = $("div.st").eq(0).text();
        let title = $(".slp").prev().eq(0).text();
        //          /// /   /   ////    /   /   /
        checkArticle(title, date, source, url, description);
    });
```

Comment: In your web server hosted you are not running your index.js code.

Comment: What do you mean? I have it set up in app.js to render the routes file pointing to 'index'  like res.render('index'). It seems like its trying to run the index.js but if the file works on my localhost why doesn't it work on the domain server?

Comment: I am terribly sorry about that it works now. It turned out I had the code trying to run in both index.js and another scripts file at the same time. Thank you

Comment: Then delete the question.